# Does any language use bound morphology to express the concept "less"?

Tags: morphology, cross-linguistic, semantics, adjectives

In English, many adjectives support the *-er* ending to express a notion of exceeding:

1. John is **taller** than Mary (is).
2. Mary is **smarter** than John (is).

Of course, you can also have the more analytic construction:

- Mary is **more intelligent** than John (is).

But with the notion of "does not exceed", *less*, only the analytic form is available:

- John is **less smart** than Mary is.
- John is **less intelligent** than Mary is.

Does any language express the *less* form using bound morphology the way we do with *-er* in (1) and (2)?

Comment: Didn't you mean "more analytic construction"?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

A diminutive is not the same as what a "less" morpheme would be — it lacks comparative semantics.

However, to answer your question, the answer is, no there is not any such language which expresses a concept of "less" synthetically, at least none has been found despite a very large (300+ language) cross-linguistic survey by Jonathan Bobalijk. See his paper "[Universals in Comparative Morphology](http://bobaljik.uconn.edu/papers/ucm201107.pdf)", for his explanation of why such a morpheme never occurs.

Comment: In case you were referring to my answer: I know exactly what the difference is between the two; fearing that there *was* no answer, I provided some information that might be interesting for the OP, though of course it is not the same thing.

Comment: By the way, I excluded the languages I knew or could check (french, spanish, german) then asked around to native speakers of: Russian, Ungarian, Lithuanian, Swedish. But nothing came out. :)

Comment: So what does this paper have to say about Turkish _-cE_, I wonder?

Comment: ...and the answer is: Turkish was one of the languages surveyed and no "less" comparative was found; in fact, it says Turkish only has analytic degrees of comparison.

Comment: To my knowledge, Bobalijk is pretty good about acknowledging counterexamples to his claims (including problematic data from Basque and Russian for his analysis of regular comparatives). So, I would need to see a paper analyzing the -cE as a less comparative, to be convinced.

Answer (score 9):

In Turkish, the suffic "-cE" gives this meaning when added to adjectives, such as "güzelce". It means that the person or thing is less beautiful than the mentioned thing. For instance:

> Annesi gibi güzelce bir kız

It means that she is less beautiful than her mother. However, in some contexts it can mean "nearly". I asked which meaning people think of when they hear words to which this suffix was added; they answered "less". 
However, this research is not very broad or scientific; I have only asked the people I could contact. Maybe this answer will help you to some extent.

I have found a [paper](http://web.ebscohost.com/ehost/detail?sid=dc329b03-7232-48dc-a84e-4e711c9290bb@sessionmgr15&vid=1&hid=12&bdata=JnNpdGU9ZWhvc3QtbGl2ZQ==#db=uvt&AN=130555) about this suffix; however, the section related to it is very little and not very much detailed.

Comment: Please give a citation for this analysis of -cE?

Comment: @Knitter, as I mentioned before, I do not have a scientific research, I have asked only the native speakers when I am suspect of this meaning as a native speaker. I will try to find a research about this topic, when I find, I will share it.

Comment: @Knitter, I cannot find a detailed research for the suffix; however, I find a little section in a paper for this meaning of the suffix. The language of the research is Turkish, so I have translated the related section.

Comment: The translation is: "the meaning of less": The suffix gives the meaning of less to the root. Initially, the meaning seems as "like,as"; however, in depth it is "less". Being an adjective or an adverb changes the meaning of the word. "topluca kız" [: the girl who is less fat], "topluca katıldık." [:we attended (the missind object) as a unity.], "fazlaca para". The link of the paper is http://web.ebscohost.com/ehost/detail?vid=8&hid=24&sid=7837d888-4a3b-49a2-935c-dccdbad2b786%40sessionmgr13&bdata=JnNpdGU9ZWhvc3QtbGl2ZQ%3d%3d#db=uvt&AN=130555

Answer (score 0):

Well, Krivoshein de Canese and Acosta Alcaraz' (2007:102) "Gramática Guarani" gives as "comparativo the inferioridad" ('inferiority comparative') the affix -ive, which attaches to the standard of comparison NP. Their example is "Susana omba'apo'ive Anagui" meaning 'Susana works less than Ana'. However, -i is a diminutive, and -ve is the comparative of superiority so... it seems that the meaning of inferiority is obtained compositionally from the superiority comparative...

Answer (score -1):

I don't know any language that does exactly what you want; but it may interest you to know that the diminutive suffix *-lus* can be used with adjectives in Latin:

**(1)** *aedes* = room, house
**(2)** *aedicula* = little room or house

**(1)** *acer* = petulant
**(2)** *acriculus* = a little/bit petulant

What's behind this is that the distinction between nouns and adjectives was not felt to be very strict in Latin: *acer* can mean "petulant" or "a petulant person/thing". But the diminutive form can certainly be used when the word is used adjectivally/attributively, as in *vir acriculus*.

Note that this suffix is productive, but it is relatively uncommon—certainly less common than English forms with "less".

Derived suffixes that work the same way are *-ulus, -culus, -(u)sculus, -(u)nculus, -illus, -ellus.* They can all indicate a diminutive or a repeated action (as in *credulus*).