# Are there languages with more than three degrees of comparison?

Tags: morphology, cross-linguistic, adjectives

In English and other languages there are three degrees of comparison: positive, comparative and superlative (e.g. tall, taller, tallest). Are there languages with more than three degrees, expressed morphologically?

Comment: Hmm so how do you envision such a fourth degree? "Tallest of three"?

Comment: There is elative (meaning: very) and its opposite - attenuative (meaning: a bit, somewhat, rather). They are different kinds of intensification, however there is no comparison (they are absolutes). So they're not really degrees of comparison.

Comment: @Cerberus I can envision a degree for "the least tall of all"

Comment: At least a lot of old grammar books treat the ***[absolute superlative](http://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/absolute_superlative)*** along with the other degrees of comparison. So it could come down to a semantics vs tradition debate or some other distinction.

Comment: By the way, if these absolute forms are not degrees of comparison, neither can **tall** be, since it's not comparing with anything. However **as tall as** is comparing with something but at least in English it's a formula rather than an inflection - I wonder if there are languages which treat it morphologically though?

Comment: I seem to recall that Hungarian has an extra degree ("excessive"). According to German Wikipedia, Basque has it as well. In English, one would use _too_ + positive. I don't have any handy sources, but maybe someone with more background can help out?

Comment: Some keywords for further research:"scalar inequality", "scalar superiority", and "scalar inferiority". Hippietrail is talking about "equative".

Comment: @OtavioMacedo: Hmm...I suppose that would be a degree of comparison, if such a (non-analytic) degree existed in a given language...

Comment: @OtavioMacedo "talleast"

Comment: @AnsgarEsztermann: Yes that is what is termed the ***[absolute superlative](http://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/absolute_superlative)*** I mentioned above. It's sometimes equated with English *too* and many languages have it, including most Romance languages, for example the *-ísimo* ending in Spanish.

Comment: http://linguistics.stackexchange.com/questions/1376/does-any-language-use-bound-morphology-to-express-the-concept-less

Comment: also see Stassen 2001 http://www.degruyter.com/view/books/9783110171549.2/9783110171549.2.10.993/9783110171549.2.10.993.xml?format=EBOK

Comment: @hippietrail: Welsh has a distinct equative. In fact, I'm going to make that an answer.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

At first, some general remarks on comparison and terminology. My answer is mostly based on [Pierluigi Cuzzolin](http://www.unibg.it/struttura/struttura.asp?rubrica=1&persona=202&nome=Pierluigi&cognome=Cuzzolin&titolo=Prof.)'s research.

Let's start with some definition of comparison. [Cuzzolin and Lehmann 2004](http://www.degruyter.com/view/books/9783110172782.2/9783110172782.2.14.1212/9783110172782.2.14.1212.xml?format=EBOK&rskey=myb4YA&result=4) give the following definition:

"Taken as a grammatical category, comparison (German Steigerung) is the formal modification of some predicative word – most often an adjective – representing a parameter of gradation
or comparison, according to the extent to which it applies to its argument, relative to some standard" (p. 1212).

Thus, comparison as a grammatical category includes "semantic" comparison (relative) and gradation (absolute).

Any comparison must contain at least the following three elements: the comparee, the parameter (a cognitively salient feature), and the parameter marker (a morpheme expressing a degree).

Secondly, Heine has a nice table on types of comparison. Naturally, there is some variation in terminology - but this is irrelevant here.

[image: Heine1997]

Cuzzolin and Lehmann 2004 argue that traditionally three degrees of comparison are recognized:

- the positive degree;
- the comparative degree, which can involve comparison of majority (smarter), comparison of minority (less smart), comparison of equality (as smart as), and even sameness (known as similative);
- the superlative degree.

Although comparison usually occurs on adjectives and adverbs, it can occur on other parts of speech, too:

Italian *canzonissima* 'the best song'

Basque *gizonago* 'more man'

The most important thing to remember about comparison is that it can be expressed by different means: morphologically, syntactically (for examples see Cuzzolin and Lehmann 2004).

Now about equative expressed morphologically (like in Welsh). Cuzzolin and Lehmann argue that it's not that common. They mention the following language groups and languages: Celtic languages, Finno-Ugric languages, Kartvelian languages, Tagalog, Indonesian, Greenlandic Eskimo, and Estonian. An example from Estonian is below:

[image: Estonian equative]

Comment: Tagalog example: "Singtangkad ko ang kapatid kong babae." The prefix "sing-" means "as ... as". tangkad - tall, ko - me or my, kapatid na babae - sister. Superlative "tallest" is "pinakamatangkad". Elative "very tall" is "napakatangkad".

Comment: Why, I wonder, does Heine separate superior and inferior comparatives, but not superior and inferior superlatives (‘David is the smartest’ vs ‘David is the least smart’)? And why no inferior elatives and excessives (‘David is very little smart/hardly smart at all’ and ‘David is not smart enough’)?

Comment: @JanusBahsJacquet valid points. I have to look it up again, it's been five years since I read it last time.

Answer (score 4):

[Welsh](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Literary_Welsh_morphology#Adjectives) has a distinct equative, as well as the comparative and superlative.

From the article linked to: *teg* "fair", *teced* "as/so fair", *tecach* "fairer", *tecaf* "fairest".

So *mor teced â* = "as fair as".

Comment: This seems to be exactly what the OP is looking for! Could you explain what a distinct equative is and provide some examples? Maybe with interlinear glosses and all that cool linguistic stuff ;-)