# Why do languages almost never have negative comparatives or superlatives

Tags: morphology

Many languages have comparative and superlative suffixes or other  morphological forms such as English ‘-er’ and ‘-est’, Latin ‘-or’ and ‘-issimus’, and Arabic ‘afʕal’ template, but I couldn’t find any kanguages with a negative comparative forms, and even some websites which claimed they don’t exist in any language. Why is that and is there truly no language which has a ‘negative comparative’ form?

PS: What tags would fit this question, I couldn’t think of any.

Comment: Most languages have negative comparative and superlative _constructions_ – English has ‘less X’ and ‘(the) least X’, for example. What they generally don’t have are negative comparative/superlative _morphological forms_, made by adding a suffix or using a template, parallel to how the positive comparative and superlative are formed. The most obvious guess at a reason would be because the negatives are much rarer than the positives – you simply need them less often(!).

Comment: Yes, mixed them up, sorry.

Comment: You may want to take a look at https://linguistics.stackexchange.com/a/2122/445

Comment: As in, likely → unlikelier (less likely) → unlikeliest (least likely)?

Comment: Not really? You can’t use that for any adjective, for example you can’t have ‘unbigger’. I was thinking something more like the opposite of ‘-er’, like some prefix or suffix that means ‘less’.

Comment: It's a nice question, but I doubt we can answer the "why" with more than speculation.